# Find directory by name and skip search in sub directories of found one

Tags: linux

I want to have synced work folders. For that I'm using Dropbox and it does not support wildcard exclude of directory (as far as I know). Since I'm mostly working on JavaScript projects, I want to exclude `node_modules` folders. solution I found so far is to use `-maxdepth` option in `find` but `node_modules` are present in different levels. Is there a way to skip the sub directory search of found directory?

```
Workspace/project1/node_modules/
Workspace/project1/node_modules/module1/node_modules
Workspace/project2/node_modules
Workspace/project2/packages/package1/node_modules
Workspace/project2/packages/package1/node_modules/module
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-prune`:

```
find Workspace -name node_modules -prune -o -print
```